# auto- instantiated bean parameters?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I'm new to spring and spring mvc

I'm going over a course where they present the following @Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class MailConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name="spring.mail.host",
        havingValue="foo",
        matchIfMissing=true)
    public MailSender mockMailSender() {
        return new MockMailSender();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name="spring.mail.host")
    public MailSender smtpMailSender(**JavaMailSender javaMailSender**) {
        SmtpMailSender mailSender = new SmtpMailSender();
        mailSender.setJavaMailSender(javaMailSender);
        return mailSender;
    }
}
```

in the second bean (smtpMailSender) - there's a parameter : 
**JavaMailSender javaMailSender**

but the parameter is not passed by the caller.

the instructors says : "**inside bean methods if we pass parameter like this one , the parameters will be injected by spring**"

My question is - how could I know that this is the expected behavior of Spring ?  what is the instructor basing this on ? 
is there a specific trait of JavaMailSender that is part of spring and therefor treated as a component or is something else in play here  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That, simply said, is the way Spring works when using Java based configuration.

When a method annotated with `@Bean` is detected and it has parameters Spring will auto wire them by default. It does so by type.

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(name="spring.mail.host")
public MailSender smtpMailSender(JavaMailSender javaMailSender) {
    SmtpMailSender mailSender = new SmtpMailSender();
    mailSender.setJavaMailSender(javaMailSender);
    return mailSender;
}
```

In this case it will inject a bean of type `JavaMailSender` into this method. As you are using Spring Boot that is configured by default and will be injected. For a more information see [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-dependencies).